# Common Quantified Self Data Formats

Tags: health-monitoring, healthvault

I am interested in understanding the state of the art regarding [Quantified Self](http://quantifiedself.com/) data sources. Specifically:

- What types of data sources should I expect to see from common QS apps?
- What types of variations I can expect in common formats (i.e. the [GPS Exchange format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format)) Samples of these formats or links to samples of these formats?
- What are common methods to access the data as an app builder?
- What are common methods to access raw data as a user/consumer?
- What are the data access policies for those devices?
- What devices matter most (please provide references to data, not mere opinion)?

I know this is a big, multipart question, but answering one part of it without the context of the others will make it difficult to make decisions about what to support and use. I plan on doing this research myself for the most popular apps. I will post my answers here, but I wanted others to be able to comment and extend that content. So if you have another app to add, consider putting it here.

Answer (score 1):

here are the common devices:

### Fitbit

- Data Type: movement data interpolated into steps/sleep data.
- Users can log other types of health data.
- Data Variations: none
- App access:
  OAuth based access to XML and JSON from [dev.fitbit.com](http://dev.fitbit.com/)
- User access: data download is a premium feature. Login to fitbit.com (and pay if you have not already) to get download access. http://blog.fitbit.com/?p=360

### RunKeeper HealthGraph

- Data Type: GPS data from the RunKeeper app, but also can pipe through fitbit withings etc
- Users can log other types of health data.
- Data Variations: none
- App access:
  OAuth based access to XML and JSON from [dev.fitbit.com](http://dev.fitbit.com/)
- User access: RunKeeper has a data download process for all users that is described here: http://support.runkeeper.com/entries/21696773-how-to-export-your-runkeeper-data

### Map My Run

- Data Type: GPS running data
- Users can log other types of health data.
- Data Variations: none
- App access:
  OAuth based access to XML and JSON from [dev.fitbit.com](http://dev.fitbit.com/)
- User access: Can download a GPX with a route but not times: http://support.mapmyfitness.com/mapmyfitness/topics/when_i_export_gpx_file_i_can_not_find_attitude_and_time_information

Comment: An update to this would be good with newer devices. For example, Fitbit Versa, data is free but in very limited form. No intraday data etc and limited to 1 month. Good article [here:](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-fitbit-says-your-data-belongs-to-you-d477270bc8d2)